# running .exe from Cygwin Terminal, issue with case-sensitive DLL names

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, shell, cygwin

Windows 10

Trying to run a win64 .exe from Cygwin terminal in a bash shell:

`C:/opt/claymore-eth/EthDcrMiner64.exe: error while loading shared libraries: OpenCL.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

However, the DLL does exist and is in the correct place - for proof, I could run the same exe from a regular Windows terminal and it works fine.

The problem is the capitalization of the DLL's file name - the name of that file is actually `opencl.dll`, which is fine under the Windows terminal (case insensitive) but not fine in Cygwin.

I know I could make a copy of the DLL with different capitalization. But is there a more general solution? Could I make win64 executables, running in a bash shell in the Cygwin terminal, become case-insensitive?

---

My end goal here is to come up with a bash script that could run under either Windows or Linux with minimal changes (some executables are named differently, and some paths differ). I have it running on Linux already.

Comment: I'm not a Windows guy, I don't use Cygwin, so this is a guess: investigate `posix=0` option for [Cygwin `mount`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mount.html).

Comment: By default cygwin like windows is not case sensitive. Where is `OpenCL.dll` and is that directory in the Cygwin `PATH` ?